# how does the ampersand(&) sign work in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, ampersand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

This is confusing me:

```
class CDummy 
{
public:
   int isitme (CDummy& param);
};

int CDummy::isitme (CDummy& param)
{
  if (&param == this)
  { 
       return true; //ampersand sign on left side??
  }
  else 
  {    
       return false;
  }
}

int main () 
{
  CDummy a;
  CDummy* b = &a;

  if ( b->isitme(a) )
  {
    cout << "yes, &a is b";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In C & usually means the address of a var. What does it mean here? Is this a fancy way of pointer notation?

The reason I am assuming it is a pointer notation because this is a pointer after all and we are checking for equality of two pointers.

I am studying from cplusplus.com and they have this example.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To start, note that

```
this
```

is a special pointer ( == memory address) to the class its in.
First, an object is instantiated:

```
CDummy a;
```

Next, a pointer is instantiated:

```
CDummy *b;
```

Next, the memory address of `a` is assigned to the pointer `b`:

```
b = &a;
```

Next, the method `CDummy::isitme(CDummy &param)` is called:

```
b->isitme(a);
```

A test is evaluated inside this method:

```
if (&param == this) // do something
```

Here's the tricky part. param is an object of type CDummy, but `&param` is the memory address of param. So the memory address of param is tested against another memory address called "`this`". If you copy the memory address of the object this method is called from into the argument of this method, this will result in `true`.

This kind of evaluation is usually done when overloading the copy constructor

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass &other) {
    // if a programmer tries to copy the same object into itself, protect
    // from this behavior via this route
    if (&other == this) return *this;
    else {
        // otherwise truly copy other into this
    }
}
```

Also note the usage of `*this`, where `this` is being *dereferenced*. That is, instead of returning the memory address, return the object located at that memory address.

Answer (score 134):

The `&` has more the one meanings:

1) take the address of a variable

```
int x;
void* p = &x;
//p will now point to x, as &x is the address of x
```

2) pass an argument by reference to a function

```
void foo(CDummy& x);
//you pass x by reference
//if you modify x inside the function, the change will be applied to the original variable
//a copy is not created for x, the original one is used
//this is preffered for passing large objects
//to prevent changes, pass by const reference:
void fooconst(const CDummy& x);
```

3) declare a reference variable

```
int k = 0;
int& r = k;
//r is a reference to k
r = 3;
assert( k == 3 );
```

4) bitwise and operator

```
int a = 3 & 1; // a = 1
```

n) others???

Comment: And bit-wise *and*

Comment: The question is specific. What does it mean in the code in the Q?

Comment: I have nothing against downvotes, but I'd like to know why so that I may learn something.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you failed to answer the question. The answer is in there somewhere, but which of the points applies to the code in the Q?

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear, but I accept your opinion. I thought a thorough explanation would help him more than just pointing out the obvious.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's obvious to me. The very fact that the question is being asked tells you that it is not obvious to rashid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I knew it was obvious to you :). Not the first time I see you around here :). What I meant was is that I thought I was pretty clear for him to understand.

Comment: an & as a function qualifier ( `void func(Obj o) &;`) denotes that the function must be passed an lvalue (new c++11 feature)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore my above comment might not be clear, the `&` qualifier means you can only call it on an lval (it's a member function)

Comment: n) others??? -    something like int&& for Rvalue reference

Answer (score 2):

Well the `CDummy& param` that is declared as a parameter of the function `CDummy::isitme` is actually a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) which is "like" a pointer, but different. The important thing to note about references is that inside functions where they are passed as parameters, you really have a reference to the instance of the type, not "just" a pointer to it. So, on the line with the comment, the '&' is functioning just like in C, it is getting the address of the argument passed in, and comparing it to `this` which is, of course, a pointer to the instance of the class the method is being called on.