# Why isn't SDL_QueryTexture assigning values to its int* arguments?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

An adjustment in my code is causing a strange occurrence which is causing segfaults. After running it through gdb, I found that a call to SDL_QueryTexture wasn't assigning the SDL_Texture's width and height values to the int pointers passed to the method. I called SDL_GetError() and printed it, and it says: "Failed loading SHCORE.DLL: The specified module could not be found." While doing searching, I heard this may have to do something with older versions of Windows. I have Windows 7, but the code was working from before, so I doubt Windows is the problem here, but the code. The code I think is causing the problem (which includes the SDL_QueryTexture call) is below:

```
struct TextTexture {

private:
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect destinationrect;
    int* w;
    int* h;

void loadText(string s) {
        SDL_Color color = {255,255,255};
        SDL_Surface* textsurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, s.c_str(), color);
        if(textsurface == NULL) {
            cout << "Could not rendertext onto surface" << endl;
        }
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r,textsurface);
        if(texture == NULL) {
            cout << "Could not make texture" << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        }
        SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, w, h);
        cout << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        SDL_FreeSurface(textsurface);
        textsurface = NULL;



    }

    void textRender(int x, int y) {

        destinationrect = {x,y,*w,*h};
        if (SDL_RenderCopy(r,texture,NULL,&destinationrect) < 0) {
            cout << "Rendercopy error" << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        }


    }
};
```

Comment: Change `w` and `h` into plain `int`s, and do `SDL_QueryTexture(..., &w, &h)`.

Comment: Where's `r` coming from?  Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are simply passing the `int` variables by value and not by pointer.
SDL was written in C, and due to this it does not have pass by reference unlike C++. So, to allow SDL to input values into your variables you need to pass the pointers to those variables

You would change this line of code:

`SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, w, h);`

To this:

`SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &w, &h);`

The ampersands return the addresses of the variables `w` and `h`.

If you would like to learn more about pointers in C++ here's a link:

[how does the ampersand(&) sign work in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857857/how-does-the-ampersand-sign-work-in-c)

Comment: `w` and `h` are `int *`, not `int`, OP needs to change that.