# Difference in declaring a variable

Tags: c++

I have declared two variables in following ways:

```
void main()
{
  int a = 20;
  int &b = a;
  cout<<a<<" "<<b;
}
```

Output: 20 20

Kindly advise what exactly happens when i write int &b = a and how is it different from the first declaration and also when to use which.

Comment: Did you try compiling this? If you did, and it compiled, your compiler is broken.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: And a modern compiler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857857/how-does-the-ampersand-sign-work-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I have changed the code now please advise on the working of the second declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does the ampersand(&) sign work in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857857/how-does-the-ampersand-sign-work-in-c)

Comment: Off-topic:  The `main` function's return type is `int` not `void`.

Answer (score 3):

> Kindly advise what exactly happens when i write int &b = a  and how is it different from the first declaration

In the example below:

```
int a;
int & b = a;
```

The `b` variable refers to the memory address of the `a` variable.  The variable `b` is just an alias for `a`.

> and also when to use which.

A common usage of references is to avoid copying large objects.  Rather than passing (copying) the large object, you pass a reference to it.

```
const std::string& Get_Tree_Name()
{
  static std::string name = "Eucalyptus";
  return name;
}
```

The above function returns a *reference* to a static string inside the function.  So rather than copying the string after the function exits, it is passing a reference.  In general, a reference would occupy less space than the `std::string` object.

Another usage is when a function modifies its parameter:

```
void Get_Pi(double& pi_value)
{
  pi_value = 3.14159264;
}

int main()
{
  double my_pi = 0.0;
  Get_Pi(my_pi);
}
```

In the `main` function of the above example, the code in the `Get_Pi` function is actually modifying the `my_pi` variable in the `main` function, because of the reference mechanism.

Without the references, the `Get_Pi` function would modify *a copy of* the `my_pi` variable and not the original variable, since parameters are passed by copy.

**Pointers vs. references**

Another alternative for a function to modify its parameter is to pass the parameter by pointer.  One issue with using a pointer is that pointer can point to *anything* and not necessarily a variable.

Passing a reference means that the object *must exist*.  A reference, unlike a pointer, doesn't need to be validated during run-time.  The compiler performs the checking.  This is important in safety critical systems.

Answer (score -2):

```
Int a = 0;
```

This a simple variable of int which can store only -32768 to 32768 (2 bytes)

```
Int * b;
```

This also a variable, the * means that this vatiable can store address of some another variable not value.

```
b=&a;
```

Now this how you put value in a pointer, writing & before a variable name will give you an address of the variable instead of variable value.

```
*b;
```

This how can get value from a pointer, this will give you a value of a

Comment: "-32768 to 32768 (2 bytes)" Not true. `int`s size is set by the compiler inmplementer. `int`'s minimum size is 16 bits (2 bytes). The upper size is unbounded, but there aren't many implementations that go over 64 bit (8 bytes). Here is a page on data type sizes and ranges : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: The rest of this answer is discussing pointers. The question does not ask about pointers. It is asking about references.

Comment: I think 20 ?? Im i Right??

Comment: Covered in the link in the first comment.

Answer (score -3):

In first variable you are assigning value to the variable a (a=20)
In second line you create a variable and give that variable address of a. 
Now b is also pointing on the adress of a. Now a and b are pointing to the same memory adress which is 20.

Comment: Pointers may or may not be involved when dealing with references. The compiler is well within it's rights to simply use two names for the same memory location.

Comment: And &b=a means address of b is equal to a. Means now b is also pointing a

Comment: You are not necessarily storing an address. `&b=a` means `b` is an alias for `a`. The compiler could quietly go through the code and replace all of the `b`s with `a`s when generating the output.